# why can't i import this file into python(pandas) using pd.read_csv( ) command line

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-cleaning

i get an error message anytime i try to import this file into python using the pandas library, it works fine for some other csv files
this same file, I easily import using Numpy as in

np.genfromtxt() ```

```
with the delimiter set.
why this difference
```

**raw_data_np=np.genfromtxt("Loan-data.csv", delimiter=';')**

raw_data_np

```
this imports the file but this 2nd code doesn't:
pd.read_csv('Loan-data.csv')
 i get a unicode decode error with a really long list of lines underneath
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the default value of the `sep` parameter (*alias delimiter*) in [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) is the comma (`,`) and not the semi-colon (`;`). You need to specify this as you did with [`numpy.genfromtext`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html).

Try this :

```
pd.read_csv('Loan-data.csv', sep=';')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\XXXXX\XXXXX\Loan-data.csv',sep=";")
```

in place of `'C:\Users\..........'` copy your file location and paste it here so you did not get any unicode error